# My EditText won't add a point to my score. android quiz app

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, radio-group

Why my program isn't adding a point to my score when I submit the correct answer. 
Please help.
Here are my variables:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int mscore =0 ;
    String q5R = "ripken";
    String q5CR = "cal ripken";
    String q5Cal = "cal";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void checkResult(View v) {
        //Access the RadioGroup view and save it to a variable.
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q1RadioBox);

        //Get the id of the RadioButton that is checked and save it
        //as an integer variable.
        int solutionId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        //Use if statements to respond based on whether
        //it is the id of the correct answer.
        if (solutionId == R.id.answer1) {
            mscore = mscore +1;
        } else {
                   mscore = mscore + 0;
               }

        //Access the RadioGroup2 view and save it to a variable.
        RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q2RadioBox);

        //Get the id of the RadioButton that is checked and save it
        //as an integer variable.
        int solutionId2 = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        //Use if statements to respond based on whether
        //it is the id of the correct answer.
        if (solutionId2 == R.id.answer2) {
            mscore = mscore +1;
        } else {
                   mscore = mscore + 0;
               }

        CheckBox ws1966 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_1966);
        CheckBox ws1983 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_1983);
        CheckBox ws1970 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_1970);
        CheckBox ws1984 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_1984);
        CheckBox ws1961 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_1961);

        // Check for Required Answers
        if (ws1966.isChecked() && ws1983.isChecked() && ws1970.isChecked() && !ws1984.isChecked() && !ws1961.isChecked()) {
            mscore = mscore + 3;
        }

        EditText questionFive = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_5);
        String questionFiveAnswer = questionFive.getText().toString();
        if (questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q5R) || questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q5CR) || questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q5Cal) ){
            mscore = mscore + 1;
        }

        EditText enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
        String name = enterName.getText().toString();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = name + " your score is: " + mscore + " points out of a possible 6 points";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Is this piece of code under your activity onCreate()  or under onClick()

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int mscore ;
    String q5R = "ripken";
    String q5CR = "cal ripken";
    String q5Cal = "cal";

Comment: I have edited it so that my entire code is up above in the question.

Comment: it seems like the if statement is not executing for some reason.

Comment: my radio buttons and checkboxes are adding points to the score, just not my edittext question.

Comment: Can you tell us the value of `solutionId ` and `R.id.answer1`? What is the value of `mscore` shown by your toast at the end?

Comment: the value of mscore at the end is 5pts and it should be 6pts

Comment: ive checked and all of the other questions are scoring correctly,  the only one not scoring is this edit text field

Comment: when you debug before your if statement what is the value of questionFiveAnswer?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Button in layout file like:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Submit"
  android:onClick="calcScore"
  android:id="@+id/button"/>
```

Now write your code in calcScore method in main activity like:

```
public void calcScore(View v)
{
    int mscore ;
String q5R = "ripken";
String q5CR = "cal ripken";
String q5Cal = "cal";



EditText questionFive = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_5);
    String questionFiveAnswer = questionFive.getText().toString();
    if (questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q5R) ||         questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q5CR) || questionFiveAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(q5Cal) ){
         mscore = mscore + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: 404 page not found :(

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/danahigz/quiz I don't see any xml layout files. Where is `R.layout.activity_main` ?

Comment: I found nothing wrong in this code. So simply copied to android studio and ran. It works perfectly fine. Nothing wrong with this code. Just be sure you are calling checkResult with onClick attribute of button. Nothing else I see going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialized int mscore first.

```
// initialize
int mscore = 0; 

// than add it
mscore += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was wrong.  But it seems to be working just fine now.  I appreciate everybody for taking their time to help.